# Warning in React js array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  let { fetching } = nextProps
  const { error } = nextProps

  if (prevState.fetching !== fetching && !fetching) {
    fetching = error
  }
  const userId =
    Object.keys(nextProps.match.params).length > 0
      ? nextProps.match.params[Object.keys(nextProps.match.params)[0]]
      : 'new'
  if (userId !== 'new') {
    const itemUser = nextProps.usersList.filter(item => {
      if (String(item.userid) === userId)
       return item
    })
    return { profileItem: { ...prevState.profileItem, ...itemUser[0] }, index: userId, fetching }
  }
  return { fetching }
}
```

It works and does what it is suppoused to do, but I want to get rid of this warning:

> Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return

It says the problem is on the line

```
const itemUser = nextProps.usersList.filter(item => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)'s callback expects you to return a boolean, you can just rewrite that line to:

```
const itemUser = nextProps.usersList.filter(item => String(item.userid) === userId)
```

The problem exists, because of this function:

```
item => {
    if (String(item.userid) === userId)
         return item
}
```

If `item.userid != userId`, you're currently not returning anything, so it implicitly returns `undefined`. It's [good practice](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/array-callback-return) to always return *something*, even if it's null or false. In this case, your function is working as expected, because the [filter callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters) expects a boolean. When you return item, item is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and thus the filter includes that item. Additionally, if you don't return anything, it implicitly returns undefined, which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and thus filters out the item.

In the end, since you're trying to return one item, you should **ideally** be using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. This will prevent excess iterations after the item is found, since you're only ever looking for exactly one item:

```
const itemUser = nextProps.usersList.find(item => String(item.userid) === userId);
return { profileItem: { ...prevState.profileItem, ...itemUser }, index: userId, fetching }
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for the answer, this worked and i learned a lot, thnx for your time